# Whats a good DIY book to learn electronics?

Tags: diy

my eldest son is in a curious age. I like him to be able to tamper with electronics, something I believe is very valuable (in terms of knowledge and learning) and has the potential to be transformative. I never got the opportunity as a kid, so I like to make up for it as well. I plan to first learn myself and then sit with him an teach him (until he begins to experiment himself).

I am searching for a book (maybe I ask for several books) that ideally goes through the history of electronics, explains how the different devices (resistor, transistor, ...) work and how to make them yourself at home from scratch using simple electronics tools (solder, wires, breadboard, ...).

I am thinking about something like building and testing the basic parts to see and understand what they do. Then buying these parts from a store to build some next level circuit. Until we arrive at something that can be programmed (I am thinking the [8-bit computer project by Ben Eater](https://eater.net/8bit)). At that point assembler language can be understood. Basically, whenever a basic principle is build by yourself, it is only a matter of manufacturing process to make it smaller and thus can be bought to make more complex projects possible.

I myself am a physicist, though one of the theoretical sort. I already understand most of the concepts but I never disgraced myself with tempering around with electronics. I now realize I missed a lot of fun and a valuable growing experience which I want to provide my sons.

I hope it is clear what I am asking for. And that this is the right forum (I thought there was a book recommendation SE but I couldn't find it).

Comment: personally I wouldn't worry too much about the history at first. Just get a kit, something like an arduino, some parts and sit down and learn how to make it work with him. You'll both have fun (at least I hope so). Getting into how the germanium and then silicon diode were developed, the PN junction, and all that other stuff - great to know, and eventually interesting, but if you start off with that he might decide that computer games are more interesting ...

Comment: How old, right now? And is the direction of this to be along the lines of reaching a point where your son can understand and perhaps design their own CPU? Or more analog? Also, how is he with mathematics? (That has a lot to do with access to some directions.) Speaking of which, what's your area? Theoretical physics is a wide topic. Could be anything from studying nothing (vacuum energy, quantum foam, etc) to something solid (3D acoustic plasmons.) [Snap Circuits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm2Sb.jpg) would be really good for a younger age.

Comment: I'd hesitate to teach soldering to someone younger than teenager. Solder irons are kind of dangerous and solder is not healthy at all - definitely invest in a proper fume extractor. As for teaching anyone with breadboards, I wouldn't recommend it at all, they are hopelessly error-prone and just a remain that people who couldn't solder used back in the through-hole days. Through-hole components are excellent for learning soldering on, however.

Comment: For an excellent  forum that supports discussion look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

DIY books are passe for nowadays generations. What I would recommend to you for him is to visit Youtube -> Simply Put. This guy is not active anymore, his last update was 3 years ago. But what he uploaded up to that point, are most of the basics your son is supposed to learn to start "playing". "Simply Put" is/was one of the best teachers I ever came across. He used a lot of demonstration, and this is what kids are attracted to.